# How to add custom field using API?

Tags: api, extension

I want to add a custom field use for activities (meeting)?
I did that using **administrator -> customize data and screen -> custom fields**

 
How can I achieve it by API 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following API call should do it.

`$result = civicrm_api3('CustomField', 'create', [
  'custom_group_id' => "GROUP_NAME",
  'label' => "CUSTOM_FIELD_LABEL",
]);`

Replace label and group name accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the API CustomGroup create to create a custom group and the CustomField API to create a custom field. I'd recommend playing with the API explorer to get exactly what you need.